# mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, because of Symfony

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi, symfony

I was writing the Security Bundle / Login Page for my website, with Symfony3.

At some point, suddenly the website started to return: **500 Internal Server Error**

I rolled back the code by commenting the last part of the code, adding `die()` or trying to access another route. Everything was and is useless. The Symfony logs are clean, they are displaying that the route was found but the Apache error log is displaying this each time I refresh the page that normally should work:

> [Sun Feb 28 17:27:19.351415 2016] [fcgid:warn] [pid 30242] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client IP_ADDRESS:57160] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
>
> [Sun Feb 28 17:27:19.351469 2016] [core:error] [pid 30242] [client IP_ADDRESS:57160] End of script output before headers: index.php
>
> [Sun Feb 28 17:27:19.844505 2016] [fcgid:warn] [pid 30242] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client IP_ADDRESS:57160] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
>
> [Sun Feb 28 17:27:19.844535 2016] [core:error] [pid 30242] [client IP_ADDRESS:57160] End of script output before headers: index.php

I tried to see where is coming from by adding `die()` just before the error is triggered and I got stuck in `HttpKernel`:

```
$event = new GetResponseEvent($this, $request, $type);

die("ss");

$this->dispatcher->dispatch(KernelEvents::REQUEST, $event);
```

In this manner the **ss** is displayed, if I move `die("ss");` after the dispatcher, I get error 500.

Any idea why is FastCGI is failing?

Thanks

Comment: files permissions problem probably.

Comment: I tried but I had no success... The weird thing is that if I run a script from the command line (bin/console script_name) it works fine, but if I try to access the website from the browser, I get error 500

Comment: Do you have any custom event listeners for the request event or do you have additional bundles enabled that do weird things when the request event is dispatched?

Comment: I have some additional bundles, but they are at their very basic...how can I check if it's their fault?

Comment: There was a problem in my code, on the Security Bundle in the unserialize method.. by mistake I wrote list(...) = $this->unserialize($serialized); instead of list(...) = unserialize($serialized); When authenticated correctly it was generating error 500 which remained cached by the server/browser.   Thank you for your answers.